# Problems with multiple one-way ANOVAs

Tags: multiple-comparisons

Could you please help me how I can conclude if I would like to know the difference between Treatment 1 and Treatment 2:

I have three groups. Treatment 1, Treatment 2 and Control.

I used multiple one-way ANOVAs to compare each pair of groups. The results are:
Treatment 1 = Control, Treatment 2 > Control, Treatment 1 = Treatment 2

If I look at the first two analyses. My conclusion would be that Treatment 2 is more effective than Treatment 1. But if I look at the last analysis I will say that Treatment 1 is the same as Treatment 2 in terms of effectiveness. This is conflicting. 
How could I conclude in this case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

First, PLEASE don't ever say that one treatment is equal to another. You have not shown they are equal, you have only failed to show that they are unequal.

Second, statistical tests do not have the transitivity property. Imagine a situation where you have samples of sizes 20, 2000, and 2, and the observed means go in the order 1st < 2nd < 3rd. Because of the larger sample sizes, you might well find a significant difference between the first two. And because of the small sample sizes, you might also NOT find a significant difference between the 1st and 3rd. Statistical testing is all about what you can prove with reasonable certainty, and what you cannot establish because of too much uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, even though it confused me even more. Maybe it was not clear in my message. By "=", I meant "not statistically significant" instead of meaning the two treatments are equal.

Comment: I know what you meant. But I really do mean to not ever say that. And understanding why is the crux of my answer. Sorry it's confusing, but try hard to understand it. Significance is as much about how much data you have as anything else.